# Executing a string or accesing actionscript compiler in execution time

Tags: actionscript-3, string, compiler-construction

I'm developing a compiler generator in actionscript 3 with flash builder 4. I need to find a way to:

1.- Execute code inside of a string.

it could be very complex code, not just trace() functions but complete code

2.- Another alternative can be to tell to the actionscript compiler to compile the code autogenerated from my compiler generator.

If someone knows at least one wat of doing this please make me know.
Thank you very much

Comment: What do you need to evaluate/execute from a string? Can't it be done normally?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the code in the string, you could eval it yourself, or use something like http://eval.hurlant.com/

Comment: Thank you, but i found limitations on both tools for my purpose :>(. The main purpose is to implement such a way to test the compiler generated by my tool kind of a debugger... and I need to pass entirely classes...

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way to do this in ActionScript 3. In ActionScript 2 you could use eval().

Possible solutions include the following:

http://www.riaone.com/products/deval/

http://eval.hurlant.com/

You know your project better than anyone - but generally there is a better way than using eval() like statements. One exception would be a scripting engine for a game - something that controls the branching within a game that you need generated from an external source. A part from this, I can't think of many times to do this